# Flutter Scaffold showing BottomAppBar Space even not requested

Tags: flutter, dart

anyone can tell me why this is happend ?
[image]

its make spacing from bottom app bar even i not write the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:orangiro_pos/utils.dart';

import '../routing_constants.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .6,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo-ww.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Login", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                          Divider(),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          titledInput(hint: "Username"),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          titledInput(hint: "Password"),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Divider(),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 55,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9 * .75 - 45,
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              child: Center(child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

this is my code, i totally dont know why this is happend. i think its generated by BottomAppBar because it have same height as i used in my dashboard.

Comment: Your widget consists of a bunch of widgets with fixed heights, and your `Column` doesn't make any use of `Expanded` widgets. Are you sure that gap at the bottom isn't merely unused space?

Comment: iam sure, i had tried to delete all widget and just make 1 container with full height and width and just color it with somr color, and that gap still apeaared

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in your `Scafflod()`:

```
child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      ...,
)
```

Comment: i cant, because i need the keyboard to resize my scaffold